# How to calculate same hash for two similar files?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to apply an Hashing algorithm, where the hash is same, If two files are similar. If one bit is lost, the hash of files change. Any algorithm which I can apply in Python to tackle this problem?

Thank you

I heard block hasing do this, but I don't know how to appply that.

I applied the following algorithm, but it does not help

```
import hashlib

file = "Annotation 2020-04-09 163448.png" # Location of the file (can be set a different way)
BLOCK_SIZE = 65536 # The size of each read from the file

file_hash = hashlib.sha256() # Create the hash object, can use something other than `.sha256()` if you wish
with open(file, 'rb') as f: # Open the file to read it's bytes
    fb = f.read(BLOCK_SIZE) # Read from the file. Take in the amount declared above
    while len(fb) > 0: # While there is still data being read from the file
        file_hash.update(fb) # Update the hash
        fb = f.read(BLOCK_SIZE) # Read the next block from the file

print (file_hash.hexdigest()) # Get the hexadecimal digest of the hash
```

Comment: As I understand it, you want a hashing algorithm that will return a similar hash if the files are similar, is that correct?

Comment: Yes @mousetail that is correct

Comment: Or something like block hash. Where we calculate X amount of hash from files. And If 80% hash matches, then files are same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire point of hashing algorithms is that they become completely different if any one bit from the source files is different, to ensure that generating hash collisions becomes challenging. Here are some workarounds:

1. The only robust way to find "similar" but not the same files you need to either compare the entire file content for every part to compute a similarity score. This is rather inefficient however, since it would be a O(n^2) algorithm with frequent hard drive roundtrips.
2. Another way is to perhaps hash only a part of each file. This will have the same problems that if only one bit of this part is different, the file will be different. However, you may be able to ignore perhaps spaces or markup or capitalization or hash only the file headers or ignore the last few bits of every color value, there are plenty of options for removing less relevant data to create less precise hashes. You could use block hashing here as a small optimization to avoid repeatedly loading big files, and first checking if enough blocks are similar.
3. You can also combine these techniques, use a hash to check if at least the basic file metadata is correct in a fast way, and then use a more slow algorithm to compute a similarity score only if the hashes match. This combines some of the accuracy of approach one with some of the speed of approach 2, though both the accuracy and the speed will still not be great.
4. The final option is to use a very weak hashing algorithm. If you just use `sum(file)%(2^32)`, similar files will give sortof similar hashes in some cases, but it's really hard to determine actual similarity based on the final hash, since a difference of a byte anywhere in the file will make a big difference in the hash still, and if you include all hashes within 256 of each other, many files will still be considered similar even if they are not and you miss all files with a difference of two bytes or more.

It depends on your use case which of these techniques work for you, but beware that this is not an easy task. Good luck!

Comment: I would say the entire point of **cryptographic** hash functions is that they become conpletely different if the input changes a bit. Normal hash function only map inputs of arbitrary size to an output of fixed size.

Comment: Yes, you are right that for non-cryptographic hash functions, the reasoning for changing the hash for every bit is a bit different, mostly because that is just the best for avoiding collisions when you have a large number of somewhat similar entries